# 'conda' commands are not working

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using basic conda commands on my system like (Anaconda 4.4.0) Python 3.6.1

```
conda info  
conda update conda
```

but it is giving error

```
fatal error in launcher unable to create process using '"'.
```

Now how to remove this error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which command is giving you an error? (you posted two)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque all the commands of conda 'conda info', 'conda list' and 'conda update conda' giving me the same error as shown above

Comment: ok - there are two possibilities that you must check: (1) are you in a different environment than the default one? (if you are unsure, type `source deactivate` in command on OSX and Linus, or `deactivate` in Windows), and try again `conda info` - if that doesn't work, (2) are you sure conda installed on your system?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque i have tried that but haven;t found it working and yes anaconda is installed on my system